# How to find the records from a table where same number records have multiple keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

My columns is like that:

```
column1 | column2
--------+--------
 100    |  01
 100    |  01
 101    |  02
 101    |  03
 102    |  04
 102    |  05
 103    |  06
 104    |  07
 104    |  07
```

And I want the output like this:

```
column1 | column2
--------+--------
101     |  02
101     |  03
102     |  04
102     |  05
```

Comment: I don't understand ... and your output doesn't help   .!!

Comment: And by the way , the records number can not repeated ..!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  c1 int,
  c2 int
)

insert into @T values
(100,       1),
(100,       1),
(101,       2),
(101,       3),
(102,       4),
(102,       5),
(103,       6),
(104,       7),
(104,       7)

;with C as
(
  select C1,
         C2,
         count(*) over(partition by C1, C2) as D1,
         count(*) over(partition by C1) as D2
  from @T
)
select C1, C2
from C
where D1 = 1 and 
      D2 = 2
```

If you want to include `103` in the result set you can use this:

```
;with C as
(
  select C1,
         C2,
         count(*) over(partition by C1, C2) as D1
  from @T
)
select C1, C2
from C
where D1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. Replace the table name with proper table name.

```
SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM dbo.TableName GROUP BY Column1,Column2
HAVING count(*)<=1
```

Please try

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select myTable.column1,myTable.column2 from myTable,
(select column1 from 
              (select distinct column1, column2 from myTable where column2 ) 
group by column1 having count(column1) > 1) tempTable 
where myTable.column1=tempTable.column1 
order by myTable.column1,myTable.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  column1,
  column2
FROM atable
WHERE column1 IN (
  SELECT column1
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY column1
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column2) > 1
)
```